Input field in SoapUI is coming as null
In soapUI when I fill up the request like this -
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:web="http://www.siemens.com/spring/soap/webservice">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <web:CustomerRequest>
         <web:customerName>user1</web:customerName>
         <web:age>5</web:age>
         <web:yearlyIncome>400000</web:yearlyIncome>
         <web:cibilScore>700</web:cibilScore>
         <web:employmentMode>govt</web:employmentMode>
      </web:CustomerRequest>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>

the console output shows -
request CustomerRequest [customerName=null, age=0, yearlyIncome=0, cibilScore=0, employmentMode=null]
Please help me resolve this error.
the lonEligibilityserviceEndpoint.java class is as follows-
package com.siemens.spring.soap.endpoint;

import javax.xml.namespace.QName;

import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.annotation.Endpoint;
import org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.annotation.PayloadRoot;
import org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.annotation.RequestPayload;
import org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.annotation.ResponsePayload;

import com.siemens.spring.soap.service.LoanEligibiltyService;
import com.siemens.spring.soap.webservice.Acknowledgement;
import com.siemens.spring.soap.webservice.CustomerRequest;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import jakarta.xml.bind.JAXBElement;


@Endpoint
public class LoanEligibilityindicatorEndpoint {
    
    private static final String NAMESPACE="http://www.siemens.com/spring/soap/webservice";
    
    @Autowired
    private LoanEligibiltyService service;
    
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoanEligibilityindicatorEndpoint.class);

    
    @PayloadRoot(namespace=NAMESPACE, localPart="CustomerRequest")
@ResponsePayload
    public JAXBElement<Acknowledgement> getLoanStatus(@RequestPayload JAXBElement<CustomerRequest> request) {
        System.out.println("request " + request.getValue());
        Acknowledgement acknowledgementResponse = service.checkLoanEligibility(request.getValue());
        
        JAXBElement<Acknowledgement> response = new JAXBElement<>(new QName(NAMESPACE, Acknowledgement.class.getSimpleName()), Acknowledgement.class, acknowledgementResponse);
        
        logger.info("This is the acknowledgement: {}", acknowledgementResponse);
        
        return response;
    }
}

I tried unwrapping the JAXB element but then the response shows this error -
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<SOAP-ENV:Header/>
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
<SOAP-ENV:Fault>
<faultcode>SOAP-ENV:Server</faultcode>
<faultstring xml:lang="en">No adapter for endpoint [public com.siemens.spring.soap.webservice.Acknowledgement com.siemens.spring.soap.endpoint.LoanEligibilityindicatorEndpoint.getLoanStatus(com.siemens.spring.soap.webservice.CustomerRequest)]: Is your endpoint annotated with @Endpoint, or does it implement a supported interface like MessageHandler or PayloadEndpoint?</faultstring>
</SOAP-ENV:Fault>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>


Check the Raw tab in SoapUI and you will know what exactly came out from SoapUI to your SOAP service. Though, looking at your description I assume it's rather a server-side issue not SoapUI.
